# Facebook executeBatchAsync and fragments

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I have a problem regarding a ListView on a fragment (that fragment extends SherlockFragment). I want to show a list of Facebook friends (I'm using executeBatchAsync on the OnCreateView method, and a custom adapter for the ListView. This adapter extends BaseAdapter). I was able to fill an array with the result, but the problem is that the fragment is always rendered first, so, it shows and empty ListView. Here's a portion of the code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group,
        Bundle saved) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guests, group, false);

    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session.isOpened()) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),
                getString(R.string.loading),
                getString(R.string.loading_friend_list));

        pd.setCancelable(false);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();

        String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN "
                + "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name";

        params.clear();
        params.putString("q", fqlQuery);

        fbRequest = new Request(session, "fql", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        try {
                            GraphObject graphObject = response
                                    .getGraphObject();

                            JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject
                                    .getInnerJSONObject();

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject
                                    .getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject friend = jsonArray
                                        .getJSONObject(i);

                                Friend f = new Friend();

                                f.setUid(friend.getString("uid"));
                                f.setName(friend.getString("name"));
                                f.setPhoto(friend.getString("pic_square"));

                                friends.add(f);
                            }

                            list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(
                                    R.id.friendsList);
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);

                            pd.dismiss();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Request.executeBatchAsync(fbRequest);
    }

    return root;
}
```

So, my question is: How I do to show the ListView properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want. So, is the list showing the data at all? Or are you asking to show something while the data loads? When do you update the data in the `adapter`?

Comment: No, the list is not showing the data. I think the problem is that the root is returned while the async request is still running, so, the ListView is empty. I don't know how to wait for the request to finish, and then, return the root view.

Comment: So you set the adapter with `list.setAdapter(adapter);`, but you didn't include where `adapter` is defined. Post that part of the code.

Comment: public class GuestsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
 private ItemAdapter adapter;
        //more code
}

ItemAdapter is a custom adapter, extended from BaseAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ItemAdapter class

```
class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return friends.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.friend_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFriendName);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgFriendPhoto);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Friend friend = friends.get(position);

        if (friend != null) {
            String name = friend.getName();
            String photoUrl = friend.getPhoto();

            holder.text.setText(name);

            imageLoader.displayImage(photoUrl, holder.image, imageOptions,
                    animateFirstListener);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the solution was very very simple! I forgot to initialize the ItemAdapter object.